# draw a huge number of text and boxes with SVG kills the browers

Tags: javascript, drawing

I have to make a kind of resource usage Gantt chart where I have 10-15 thousand resources and 1 to 30 task assigned to them.
I have to display information bubbles when the user hovers the mouse over the task and also I have to able to drag and drop them along (to assign them to an other resource)
SVG would be fine for all this, but for that amount of text and boxes I'm exploding the DOM and the browsers resources.
How can I achieve this?
It must not specifically be done in SVG, canvas, or plain html is fine as well if it can handle this amount of resources/task, and if I can make all the required mouse activities.

Or said in a different way: How can I display 50 thousand interactive boxes (points, markers, texts. etc.)  in a performant manner?

Here is more or less what I want to achieve (it is done with svg.js), but for 15 thousand rows.
[image]

Comment: No user can digest that many rows at one time. Render what user needs at any given time

Comment: Unfortunately my users can. This is an overview of the resources and they have to see to actual state of them. (the gray box are the planned activities, the red one are the actual ones). This is a month view. And once they see where they have to act (have a first opinion), they will reduce the number of resources and the span of periods.

Comment: I would recommend using other than svg approaches (2d canvas for instance). SVG is good for <1000 nodes as you pointed rightly that it basically expands your DOM tree.

Comment: @Sergey, I was thinking of a Canvas approach but than I will lose (or make it very difficult) the interactivity (i.e. displaying additional information on mouse hover and drag&drop)

Comment: So based on the image you show as example - why would you need to render all of 15k nodes? Most likely u only need a subset visible on the screen, the rest is just data. Is there a view where u have to show all 15k simultaneously??

Comment: I was doing simple “infinite” scroll with SVG a while ago, i am sure depending on your target UX you could leverage same approach (only render what should be visible)

Comment: A kind of "virtual DOM" would be absolutely fine. As a grid I'm using the nice w2ui grid, where I'm displaying several ten thousands of records (because it is needed so) and it is working fine. But I do not know how to do that with this kind of "images". In fact the best way would be if I could find a good charting or Gantt tool which could do all of my requirements (task quantity and interactivity)

Comment: @Gabor you will not get around reducing your node count for the user. You cannot just move the responsibility for the whole thing to some magic libraray. Dont show the nodes which are not visible to the user and it will work like a charm. There are multiple possibilities in the web to achieve something like that

Comment: Well, I'm unfortunately not a big magician of javascript infinite scroll, where I can load only the nodes required. Especially not for such graphical items